# PyMongo - Query documents with a field if it's given?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm sending a request to my API through an HTTP get, and this route recieve the request, get the url parameters and store them as variables .

I have a collection, which I would like to query based on the value of this parameter, normally I would use :

`docs.find({"doc_type":doc_type,"year": year...})`

But some parameters are empty, I would like to know if there's a function that would allow me to filter using that parameter value if it's not empty, otherwise if it's empty then it does not filter using that parameter .

**Example :** I have a list of documents, each document has a Module, Year and Category field, if the module given in the url is empty, I should only query using the Module and Year, if year url parameter is empty I should query only using Module and Category field, if year and module url params are empty I should only query based on Category field and so on .

I'm looking for some way to do this without using several if/else

Comment: Why don't you just filter the query dictionary and clear the empty ones before giving it to the `.find` method?

Comment: Oh didn't think about that, thank you, could you make this as a response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have built the `query` somehow, you can remove the empty string or None values from it:

```
query = {"doc_type": "type" ,"year": "", "url": "test_url"}
filtered_query = {k: v for k, v in query.items() if v is not None and v != ""}
docs.find(filtered_query)
```